# Getting Problem in Express.js on nodemon running server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

[enter image description here][1]This is the problem which I facing how to solve

see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- nodemon -h
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

  ***Problem Image Linke
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCqrK.png***
  ```

Comment: Please share your code to help readers to understand your issue better.

Comment: pic is in the link you can check it

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCqrK.png

Comment: Its a windows error

Comment: Yes what can I do to solve